# XSP.partialRefreshPost is not working on IBM Bluemix Xpages runtime

Tags: xpages, ibm-cloud

I am trying to refresh a control (by id 'previewPane') in 'onComplete' event of an action button using:

```
XSP.partialRefreshPost('#{id:previewPane}').
```

It works fine on my test server Domino 9.0.1(not on bluemix).

On Bluemix it is throwing the error:

> "CLFAD0380E: No component found with ID
>   $$xspsubmitid=view:_id1:previewPane to handle the submit event".

Is there a way to fix this.

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

This is due to feature enhancement work in this area and associated function.  It is specific to the current XPages Buildpack release on Bluemix, hence the reason that it is not effecting your test Domino 9.0.1 server.

You can suppress the validation error message handling by including the following XSP property in your application's xsp.properties file and redeploying to Bluemix:

xsp.error.disable.0380=true

An upcoming release of the XPages Buildpack will include the full enhancement and attempt to resolve the current regression you are experiencing.

Comment: Just upgraded to V10 and experienced this issue 3 years down the line. This fix works.